# Does Time Actually Ever Stop?

Tags: cosmology, time, universe

I have been thinking about this question and can answer that time does not in fact ever stop.

Time is the measurable distance between two particles where a reaction takes place between the two particles in a medium that reacts, causes a reaction or bounds a reaction taking place between particles where the distance of the medium can be measured as well as the distance of the particles travelling in the medium and then reacting as well.

Therefore time does not stop. Time might slow to a relative standstill but some action of time is constantly taking place around the two particles creating a measurable distance.

I was also thinking about particles that are consumed by a black hole. It is said that time stops inside of black hole. If particles are packets of light that are translated as data do stop after they cross the event horizon of a black hole then each time the packet of data or information is pulled into the black hole and stops it is occupying the same exact space inside of the black hole that it had occupied on the other side of the black hole before being pulled into the black hole. Thus recreating the object pulled into the black hole on the other side of the black hole possibly.

I also think that a black hole functions much the same that the human eye functions in so much that light is seen by the eye and converted into data within the brain that humans then try and figure out what the object is.

Light does not escape the 'black hole' of the human eye much the same it does not escape the event horizon of a black hole. In both cases visible light is recorded and analyzed by the brain and stored.

So does a black hole store the light that it takes into its event horizon in the form of being new planets and solar systems that would be present on the fringe of another expanding Universe? Much like our Universe is expanding are there galaxies just on the other side of the edge of the Universe that come into being as their recorded data passes through the event horizon of a black hole and is reproduced for us to see in our Universe?

Comment: The question of whether or not time actually ever stops is nonsensical in the way you originally phrased it. The word "stops", in this context, means that nothing happens from one moment of time to the next. So you seem to be questioning whether or not there is a change in time for one system between two distinct moments of time. The question is premised on a presupposed answer. Even if you modify it to properly include relativity, either the same argument holds or you are considering the rest frame of something that is never at rest. The question is still, technically, nonsensical

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of time seems a bit nonsensical.

Also, Proper time [i.e. the time that you yourself experience] is invariant. Regardless of how fast you go, or how close to the centre of the black hole you get, to you time will always be progressing at the same rate.

I don't understand what basis you have for your statements about black holes either. It'd be best if you're asking questions in a physics stackexchange to perhaps not stray from questions with meaning or reason. A Black hole is just defined by a boundary condition, a surface where the escape velocity is $>c$.

Answer (score 2):

***tl;dr*-**  Time is an ordering metric.  You can suppose that no future member of a set will occur after some maximal index, at which point you might say that time has "stopped", but that's probably more of a simplification of the situation than a fact about the situation.

#### Time's an ordering construct

The most general notion of "time" is that it's an ordering construct.  We can say that things happened "earlier" or "later" as a function of this order.

The simplest notion of time is Newtonian, which is when there's a clear, universally agreeable sequencing that all events can be placed into.

Back when Einstein was figuring out his theory of relativity, he couldn't get all of the events into a clean, ordered sequence, forcing him to abandon the notion of a universally agreeable sequencing.  However, he still had the concept of things happening in some sort of order, so he still had "time" in specific contexts.  Trying to fit these timelines together and matching up the resulting descriptions was how he constructed relativity.

#### What would "stopped" time be?

If time's just a way to describe the order of events, what would it mean for time to be "stopped"?  Can you "stop" an ordering construct?

Perhaps the closest thing you can get to "stopped" time is some sort of assertion that, after some specific point in the ordering, there shouldn't be anything describable.

#### Observer perceiving stopped time

Say that you're watching some region with arbitrarily powerful time dilation, like the black hole that you're asking about.  In this region, events slow so much that you suppose that, at some point, no new describable event will occur.  Then you might say that time has "frozen" or "stopped".

However, that's less of a truth and more of a model reduction, wherein you remove any mechanism for describing later events from your model.